# Write files outside of a docker container via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, containers, docker-machine

Is there a way to write files (json in this case) to outside of the docker container?
I'm taking about the most simple way, for example:

```
data = {"id":"1","name":"sample"}
with open('name.json','w') as fp:
   json.dump(data,fp,indent=4)
```

is there a way to make this write outside of the docker container? or in a specific place?
or to save it on a specific path on the system that the container will run on?

Comment: Mount an outside path to an inside path when starting the container, then write to the inside path from inside the container.

Comment: Im pretty new to containers.. not really sure what that means... could you elaborate a bit more or send some docs regarding this? thanks!

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Much appreciation!

Comment: If the goal of your application is to read and write host files, and you're running on a MacOS or Linux system that has Python preinstalled anyways, I wouldn't bring Docker into it; just directly run the Python script.

Comment: The docker is a request of the customer, so it's a must.
ideally i would build an API that would write these files outside to a DB.. but there is not internet connection over there. so the only way to write output is using this method (alteast for the thing that he wants).

So I need a docker :/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume

- your python script has the location `/app/myscript.py` in your docker container.
- the location for where your python script should write the files is `/home/jon/result_files/`
- your docker image is called `mypyimg`

Then you can use **volumes** to mount a host location when starting your container:

```sh
docker run -d \
  --name my_py_container \
  -v /home/jon/result_files:/app \
  mypyimg
```

Comment: that is good, but what if I am hosting the container in Azure. How can I control the volume to mount?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with Azure but you might want to consult their documentation. Maybe this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files