# How to upload file outside Docker container in Flask app

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-restful

I'm new into Docker. I have a problem with uploading file in Flask app that is contained in Docker and accessing it.

Let's say that I have a project in this structure:

```
/home
| /myProjects
  | /myDockers
  | | /myApp
  | | | /controller
  | | | ...
  | | | wsgi.py
  | | | .gitlab-ci.yml
  | | | DockerFile
  | | | gunicorn.sh
  | /uploads
```

My Flask app is in /MyApp, while I want to upload file into /uploads. The app was deployed on Docker with these configurations:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-image:
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
  script:
    - cd /home/myProjects/myDocker/myApp/
    - git checkout dev
    - git pull origin dev
    - docker container rm -f myApp
    - docker image rm -f myApp
    - docker build -t myApp -f 20021_DockerfileLmsGeneralRepositoryService .

deploy-container:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
  script:
    - docker run -d --network host -e DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL -e REDIS_HOST=$REDIS_HOST --name myApp myApp
```

**DockerFile**:

```
FROM python:3.8.7-slim-buster AS compile-image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc libpq-dev && apt-get install -y apt-utils

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade --user -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install injector


COPY . /code

FROM python:3.8.7-slim-buster AS build-image
COPY --from=compile-image /code/ /code
COPY --from=compile-image /root/.local /root/.local

# Make sure scripts in .local are usable:
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /code

RUN chmod a+x gunicorn.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","./gunicorn.sh"]
```

**gunicorn.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
gunicorn wsgi:application -w 2 --threads 2 --preload -b 0.0.0.0:20021
```

I already create an API in my Flask app to upload file and succeed in local (Windows) PC, but then when I deploy it into the development server, the structure of folder is different from what I expected. When I checked the project structure using script, it returned:

```
"/code/controller"
```

Which is different from the structure of the project in the server, so I ask my senior and he said I should learn about Volume in Docker since the project is contained inside Docker container, but I never used Docker in the first place.

I also already tried to change the script in **.gitlab-ci.yml** into this (I tried this from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346181/write-files-outside-of-a-docker-container-via-python)) and yeah it doesn't work:

```
- docker run -d --network host -e DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL -e REDIS_HOST=$REDIS_HOST --name myApp -v /home/myProjects/:/root/.local/code myApp
```

Comment: You should not need a `-v` option to overwrite the application code, nor should you need a `--network host` option to disable Docker networking.  The directories in your Dockerfile don't seem to match your initial description, which is also a little confusing.  What command exactly are you running to "check the project structure"?  Does the application run?  If you upload files into it, where do they wind up?

Comment: Well, the reason for the different file system structure is inside your Dockerfile: You copy everything of your current directory (which should be the directory `myApp` i guess, because thats where your Dockerfile is in) into a directory `code` of your docker image / container (it gets created if it does not exist yet). The result is `/code/controller`. I'm not sure why you should use a volume here, btw.

Comment: @DavidMaze here is the thing. The app does run, but when I upload the file, I cannot track it. I'm not the one that made the Docker script here, I just asked to create an API to upload and download the file. The project folder structure is exactly what I described before, but because of the project run on Docker container, when I check the structure folder of Controller API that I made, it returns as `/code/controller` which is different with the folder structure that I described before.

Comment: @Manu , well I just instructed to learn about Docker Volume to deal with this, I don't know if this a right approach or not as I really don't know anything about Docker

Comment: @Ibnu A volume is basically just a file or directory located on your host system that you put into the container before start. This way, you'd have a development image for your app where you can always mount the current status of your app files into the container instead of having an image with a fixed version of your app where the corresponding files of your app are included in the image already. I just dont see a big advantage here because as far as i know you cant change the volume without stopping the container, so you would have to restart it all the time when you updated your app files.

Comment: @Manu That's what I afraid of, every time I push the project to the Git, it will automatically re-deploy the app. So I'm afraid all uploaded file will be erased each time I push the update. So what should I do?

Comment: @Ibnu I have no experience with gitlab CI, but if you can access the gitlab CI server, you could create a directory containing all files you want to be "uploaded" out of the box. Then, in `.gitlab-ci.yaml` , add a volume of this directory to your docker deployment (in `/uploads` inside the container). Now the container always contains these files, so the files are available in every deployment from now on. You can add further files whenever you want, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our talk, I could see another and easier solution. parts of my other answer are still applying.

---

from your working folder structure, your app seems to try writing to `../../uploads` folder, 2 levels up in directory structure. thus we can create a folder structure in the container to suit this.

in `Dockerfile` make these changes:

- edit `COPY --from=compile-image /code/ /code` to `COPY --from=compile-image /code/ /code/app`
- edit `WORKDIR /code` to `WORKDIR /code/app`
- add `RUN mkdir /uploads` anywhere **after** `FROM .. AS build-image` and but **before** `ENTRYPOINT`

we copy the app 2 level deep in the container and adding uploads folder into root.

now run change your run command into this:

```
docker run -d --network host -e DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL -e REDIS_HOST=$REDIS_HOST --name myApp -v /home/myProjects/uploads:/uploads myApp
```

we bind-mount an uploads folder in the host into the uploads folder in the container. you can have the bind as `-v path_to_your_uploads_folder_in_host:/uploads`

Answer (score 1):

you are using `cd /home/myProjects/myDocker/myApp/` in CI file and `COPY . /code` in docker build file.

that means "whatever you see in host's `/home/myProjects/myDocker/myApp/` folder, copy them all into `/code` folder of the container". thus your `...myApp/*` becomes `/code/*`

but your pain is not just that. from the app' perspective, you are writing uploaded files into `../../uploads` but you don't have such a folder in your container. also note that you have 2 parent levels in your host and your app is looking for such a path and won't find inside the container anyways because your project is only 1 level deep from the root level.

in this latter situation, change your code to read uploads folder path from the environment (`os.environ?`), set default to be `../../uploads` for your development, create a folder inside your container such as `/uploads`, add its path in your docker file with `ENV` then map host and container upload folder paths with volume command, possibly `-v home/myProjects/uploads:/uploads`

---

edit:

I have written a simple app doing the above last paragraph. please visit this address: https://github.com/yilmazdurmaz/basicbindmount

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I understand what you mean about my situation. How can I create folder inside my container?
I think I don't have access to open /code from the server credential that was given to me. I only have access to project folder that I described before, not the container location.

Comment: @IbnuAgielsAlthur this need a little more information from your side; where this container runs, who owns/runs it, what resources you have access rights on your host and how you access this host. if you use your own home directory and you run the container you own every right inside the container. if all things run by someoneelse all you need is access to the host and uploads folder in it and you dont need access into container. and also again, it is important where your code tries to store those uploaded files inside container.

Comment: @IbnuAgielsAlthur a container is accessible by its running user in the host machine, so if you run it you are the root user of it. but even so, you don't need access to the container when running this "bind-mount"'ed folder in your command. all you need is finely defined upload folder in your flask code and have that folder inside container plus your mount folder in your host. and if run by someone else, then you only need access to their host-side upload folder set in the run command to read files in it.

Comment: @IbnuAgielsAlthur one last thing: that `/root/.local` in dockerfile is just to copy some run scripts created during the app's build process in `compile-image` and required for your app to run from `build-image`. you can see it is added to system's PATH. but your app is copied into and runs from inside `/code` folder. this might clear few things in your mind. as for the location of the uploads folder, please check app's code and settings files and bind-mount that folder

Comment: About accesses, I can access where the project got deployed which is located in ```/home/myProjects/myDocker/myApp``` , while my credential for server not a root, which mean I cannot access ```/root/.local```, and most likely the Docker in myApp run in ```/root/.local/code/myDocker/myApp/``` which I know from running a script into myApp to mapping all available folder from the root of Docker Container, though I don't know if my assumption is right or not.

Comment: All files that I pushed to Git will be uploaded to ```/home/myProjects/myDocker/myApp``` and will be deployed using Docker automatically. But I have access to tamper with all **.gitlab-ci.yml**, **DockerFile**, and **gunicorn.sh**

Comment: let's say that I don't want to ```COPY . /code```, then what should I do after removing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240599/discussion-between-ibnu-agiels-althur-and-yilmaz-durmaz).